# Can I make autscroll=false for some specific states in angular-router-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app I'm using `autoscroll="true"`

```
<ui-view autoscroll="true">
</ui-view>
```

and that's desired behaviour for the most cases.

But can I set `autoscroll=false` for some specific states (like, for example, when content is appended to the bottom of the page)?

Comment: I know that the docs stated that I can use an expression in `autoscroll` attribute, but is there any examples that shows how to combine changing of the state with switching autscroll variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make service name it scrollService

```
app.service('scrollService',function(){
    var self = this;
    self.scrollEnabled = false; //default scroll Status
    self.enable = function(){
      self.scrollEnabled = true;
    }
    self.disable = function(){
      self.scrollEnabled = false;
    }

});
```

// this controller will be parent controller for the ui-view element

```
app.contoller('bodyCtrl',function(scrollService){
   var ctrl = this;
ctrl.scrollService = scrollService;

})
```

// let's assume this controller will be the current state controller

```
app.controller('usersCtrl',function(scrollService){
// if i need this state to be auto scroll 
scrollService.enabled();
// if i need to prevent auto-scroll 
scrollService.disable();
})
```

// for the HTML must be like

```
<body ng-controller="bodyCtrl as ctrl">
 <ui-view autoscroll="ctrl.scrollService.scrollEnabled" ></ui-view>
</body>
```